# changing bootstrap btn css and hover action issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap for building navigation menu and I'm changed buttons from primary class to inverse where I'm further customize inverse class with inline css to suit my look and feel needs.

```
.btn-inverse {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: silver;
}
```

The only problem is that on mouse hover and drop down menu click menu title on that element remains hardly visible (almost invisible)

since generated html code is

```
<button class="btn btn-inverse active dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button">
   Menu item
   <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

i tried with

```
.btn-inverse :hover {    
    color: white!important;
}
```

but that doesnt help.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no space before :hover

```
.btn-inverse:hover {    
   color: white!important;
}
```

try this

Comment: You don't need the !important because :hover is alot more specific

Answer (score 1):

No spaces before using hover selector (as YangLi already answered) and in this case you don't need an `!important` declaration here. 
If this style is inlined as you said than this will work also

```
.btn-inverse:hover {    
    color: white;
}
```

[When to use the important css declarations](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/)